# What change to be made in makefile to include protobuf

Tags: c++, makefile, protocol-buffers

Makefile:

```
CFLAGS = -c -g -W -O3 -Wall -Werror -Wshadow \
-Wno-long-long -Wpointer-arith -D_REENTRANT \
-D_POSIX_PTHREAD_SEMANTICS -DLINUX2 \
-I ./acl/lib_acl_cpp/include
BASE_PATH=./acl
LDFLAGS = -L$(BASE_PATH)/lib_acl_cpp/lib -l_acl_cpp \
-L$(BASE_PATH)/lib_protocol/lib -l_protocol \
-L$(BASE_PATH)/lib_acl/lib -l_acl \
-lpthread
redisConnection: redisConnection.o
    g++ -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS)
redisConnection.o: redisConnection.cpp
    g++ $(CFLAGS) redisConnection.cpp -o redisConnection.o
```

And I have generated the nrtprofile.pb.cc and nrtprofile.pb.h with the help of protoc command.

What changes must be made in the makefile because I am getting the following error in the class redisConnection.cpp when I am using the functions:

```
undefined reference to `google::protobuf::MessageLite::ParseFromString(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
```

I have included nrtprofile.pb.h in the redisConnection.cpp

As here there are two things redisConnection and redisConnection.o, I am getting confused where should I write nrtprofile.pb.cc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: I added -lprotobuf to the LDFLAGS. Still it does not recognize the classes in nrtproto.pb.cc. Where should I include in the makefile?

Comment: Every `.cc` or `.cpp` file should be compiled separately into a `.o` file and linked together into your `redisConnection` binary at the end.

Comment: It worked. Thanks a lot!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Add `-lprotobuf` to the `LDFLAGS` variable.

However, this assumes that the protobuf library is installed in a location where the linker finds it (e.g. /usr/lib). If you have it somewhere else, you can provide the additional search path by setting the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` variable like this: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/my/special/path`.

Comment: Thanks!. This has removed the error of ParseFromString.  But still raising errors like undefined reference to `nrtprofile::RedisNewsMessage::RedisNewsMessage()'.

Comment: I think I also need to include nrtproto.pb.cc somewhere in makefile

Answer (score 0):

You can find the needed linker and compiler flags [here](https://github.com/google/protobuf/tree/master/src). Basically, compiler and linker-related, you need to do something like `` c++ my_program.cc my_proto.pb.cc `pkg-config --cflags --libs protobuf ``